# PhantomJS push all onNavigationRequested callbacks to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have a phantom js script that checks every redirection and shows it in the console by the `page.onNavigationRequested` callback method.

but when i want to catch all the URLs that returned from the `page.onNavigationRequested` callback method and pushed them to an array and finally show all the URLs at the end of the script, it only shows the first redirection URL.

can you please check the script and advice.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var sys = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var response = {};
var arrayOfResponses = [];
var pageUrl = 'http://example.com/r1.php';

phantom.onError = function (msg, trace) {
    phantom.exit(1);
};

function forceExit(){
   phantom.exit(0);
}

page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
    arrayOfResponses.push(url) ;
}

response.content = arrayOfResponses;

page.open(pageUrl, function(status) {
    if ( status !== 'success' ) {
        phantom.exit( 1 );
    } else {
        phantom.exit( 0 );
    }
}, 100);

setTimeout(forceExit,2000);

console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your script:

1. You make PhantomJS exit too early, after the first url is opened. It doesn't have time to follow redirects.
2. You write the script from top to bottom as if the program flow is linear/synchronous, whereas in javascript it's not — `onNavigationRequested` can be called many times.

So with that in mind let's rewrite the script to collect all the redirects and exit if no new redirect is made for 2 seconds.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var response = {};
var arrayOfResponses = [];
var pageUrl = 'http://admin.weeqo.com/redirect/r1.php';
var exitTimeout;

// This will be called if no redirects are requested in 2 seconds
function forceExit(){
    // Just for fun we'll note the final URL
    var curURL = page.evaluate(function(){ 
        return document.location.href 
    });
    console.log("Final URL is " + curURL);

    // Prepare and output the report:
    response.content = arrayOfResponses;
    console.log("List of all requested URLs: " + JSON.stringify(response));

    // Now we can exit safely
    phantom.exit(0);
}

// This is called before each redirect
page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {

    // Clear timeout so that script is not shut down
    // because we have a new redirect
    if(exitTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(exitTimeout);
    }
    arrayOfResponses.push(url);
    console.log("Navigation requested: " + url);

    // Create timeout that will shut down the script
    // in two seconds unless cancelled
    exitTimeout = setTimeout(forceExit, 2000);
}

// open the first page
page.open(pageUrl, function(status) {

    // We only care for errors because
    // who knows how many time will pass before 
    // we hit the last redirect
    if ( status !== 'success' ) {
        phantom.exit( 1 );
    }
});
```